# XML-22900: (Fatal Error) An internal error condition occurred

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am facing this weird issue. I was working on a project, I had written some code to generate and XML using XML parser. The thing is when i run the code when on my local system, it runs fine. But when i deploy the code on to the environment, i doesn't. I am suspecting some sort of JAR thing. But i cant quite place it.

```
XML-22900: (Fatal Error) An internal error condition occurred.

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at oracle.xml.xslt.XSLEventHandler.characters(XSLEventHandler.java:866)
at oracle.xml.xslt.XSLTContext.reportNode(XSLTContext.java:426)
at oracle.xml.xslt.XSLTContext.reportNode(XSLTContext.java:390)
at oracle.xml.xslt.XSLTContext.reportNode(XSLTContext.java:390)
at oracle.xml.xslt.XSLTContext.reportNode(XSLTContext.java:1340)
at oracle.xml.xslt.XSLCopyOf.processAction(XSLCopyOf.java:136)
at oracle.xml.xslt.XSLNode.processChildren(XSLNode.java:480)
at oracle.xml.xslt.XSLTemplate.processAction(XSLTemplate.java:205)
at oracle.xml.xslt.XSLStylesheet.execute(XSLStylesheet.java:581)
at oracle.xml.xslt.XSLStylesheet.execute(XSLStylesheet.java:548)
at oracle.xml.xslt.XSLProcessor.processXSL(XSLProcessor.java:339)
at oracle.xml.jaxp.JXTransformer.transform(JXTransformer.java:454)
... 3 more
```

The input is the same, the code is the same, not sure what else i can provide, if you do need some more info let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same error. The error seems to be related to the transformer being used. Try using the Xalan factory.

`TransformerFactory factory = new org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl();`

Comment: I forgot about this. I was able to figure out what was wrong. But cant quite remember what the solution was. From what i can remember, it was more or less an XML format error. When I ran it on my local, from a standalone XML input it worked fine. But the XML that was getting generated at runtime which was the input not correctly formed. Shucks, i wish had remembered about this post!

Comment: This is the correct answer. Spring has been wiring the wrong transformer factory, not capable of doing the job. Setting the transformer factory explicitly solved the problem. Awarding the bounty.